# AngularJS ng-repeat only for Items with a Specific Subfield

Tags: angularjs

How can I get ng-repeat to only repeat items which contain subfields? I have a list of videos that updates based on language preference. I want to do something like ng-repeat="video in videos" only where ng-show="video.title[videoLanguage]" would make the element show. When I try using ng-show, it works somewhat but I have other code that works based on the length of the videos list (which updates since not all the videos are available in every single language).

Here's my code:

```
            <ul ng-init="select=0" ng-style="{'margin-top': ((videoContainerHeight - (videos.length * 160)) / (videos.length - 1)) * select}">
                <li ng-repeat="video in videos" ng-class="{'selected': select == $index}" ng-click="$parent.select=$index; changeNextPage(video.url);">
                    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
                    <div class="title">
                        <div class="title-cell">
                            <h2 ng-bind="video.title[videoLanguage]"></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Videos list object:

```
 {
    "id": "videos",
    "url": "/videos",
    "view": "views/videos.html",
    "nextPage": "#/home",
    "videos": [{
        "url": "#/videos/extraction",
        "thumbnail": "img/thumbnails/thumbnail.jpg",
        "title": {
            "english": "Short Title"
        }
    }, {
        "url": "#/videos/extraction",
        "thumbnail": "img/thumbnails/thumbnail.jpg",
        "title": {
            "english": "Longer Title Here",
            "spanish": "Hi"
        }
    }, {
        "url": "#/videos/extraction",
        "thumbnail": "img/thumbnails/thumbnail.jpg",
        "title": {
            "english": "This is a Really Really Really Long Title",
            "spanish": "Hi"
        }
    }, {
        "url": "#/videos/extraction",
        "thumbnail": "img/thumbnails/thumbnail.jpg",
        "title": {
            "english": "Short Title",
            "spanish": "Hi"
        }
    }]
   }
```

I'm looking to have ng-repeat generate a 4 item list when the language is set to english and a 3 item list when the language is set to Spanish.

Comment: question is not clear, can you show videos list objects

Comment: so you want to show only those videos which have title in specific language?

Comment: Yeah. If something in the $rootScope says language = english I want ng-repeat to show 4 items but if it's spanish I want it to show 3 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle , I think this is exactly what you want, ahve a look

https://jsbin.com/dinuku/edit?html,js,output

I created a filter to filter items based on language

```
app.filter('languageFilter', function() {
  return function(array, lang) {
    return (array || []).filter(function(item) {
      if (lang in item.title) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I  suggested you  the  ng-switch
[ng-switch doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)